# Opening Android Notification Settings programmatically

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-settings

I need to take a user that has Notifications disabled for my app to the system notification screen.

I can't seem to find the option for

Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.{Notifications})

Does anyone know of an option besides going to

Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this solution to redirect the user to notification settings.

```
Intent settingsIntent = null;
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
                           .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                           .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, mActivity.getPackageName());
 }
 mActivity.startActivity(settingsIntent);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"));
```

This will open settings activity with notifications settings.

Comment: I have tried that and it only show one option com.tmobile.pr.adapt

Comment: Give us some more that. Which android are you using ? Which vendor of device because it may vary...

Comment: Samsung S7 T-Mobile, Android 6.0.1